# Arrays as values in a Dictionary in Swift: Cannot append values

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary, append

I want a function to append an object Something to an array of Somethings, as a value inside a Dictionary. If the key does not exist, I want to create it. If **theDictionary[aCategory]** is empty, It wont enter the **if var** statement (because is **nil**), so I really don't know how to solve it. I'm sure with force unwrapping I will solve it, but really want to use a more safe way, like optional biding.

```
private var theDictionary: [Category:[Something]] = [:]
public func add(aSomething: Something, aCategory: Category{
    if var arrayOfSomethings = theDictionary[aCategory]{
        arrayOfSomethings.append(aSomething)
        theDictionary[aCategory] = arrayOfSomethings
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to handle the `else` condition:

```
if var arrayOfSomethings = theDictionary[aCategory]{
    arrayOfSomethings.append(aSomething)
    theDictionary[aCategory] = arrayOfSomethings
} else {
    theDictionary[aCategory] = [aSomething]
}
```

Comment: Replace this entire block with `theDictionary[aCategory, default: []].append(aSomething)`.